# Performance tuning for storm with kafkaspout

Tags: apache-storm

I have been doing performance tuning for Storm topology with KafkaSpout. I was able to achieve 12000 tuples per sec with the following additions:

- No. of workers: 3
- No. of partitions of the topic: 6
- No. of spout threads: 6

`storm.yaml` setting:

```
TOPOLOGY_EXECUTOR_RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE, 16384
TOPOLOGY_EXECUTOR_SEND_BUFFER_SIZE, 16384
TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING, 10
TOPOLOGY_ACKER_EXECUTORS, 3
```

My cluster has 3 supervisors. Could you please suggest what additions that we should do to reach more than 50k per sec?

Comment: Your question is very hard to answer. The max throughput depends on multiple factor like execution environment (ie, type and speed of CPU, number of cores, network, cluster or cloud, maybe main memory) and the kind of computation you perform. How many spout/bolt (logically) to you have; how are those connected; what is the used dop for each? Do you execute with or without fault-tolerance? **Even if you give all this information, it might still be very hard to provide help. Tuning topologies is all but trivial.**

Comment: It depends also on what are you doing with those tuples. For example you might be writing your results to some persistent storage like HBase. That might become a limiting factor in execution time. Full working information would be helpful.

Comment: I am using KafkaSpout to pull the messages from kafka topic (having 6 partitions) and then one bolt which will parse the data  in JSON format and writes to HBase. Please advise me.